# ¿Es posible usar un valor de javascripts en razor asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente valor de javascripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var variable_js=10;
</script>
```

y en razor, una variable de asp.net, le deseo asignar el valor de javascripts que declare. Por ejemplo:

```
@Dim variable_vb=variable_js '¿se puede??
```

¿Se puede hacer algo así como lo declarado arriba?y ¿Como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas realizar no es posible. Algo que es importante entender entre código en **Razor** y **javascript**, que el primero es procesado del lado del servidor y el otro es ejecutado en el cliente (es decir el browser).

Cuando realizas una solicitud de cierta página, esa página se procesa en el servidor y luego de recibida por el navegador, es procesado el código del lado del cliente (javscript, css, html, etc).

Por lo tanto, como podrás concluir no es posible realizar lo que mencionás. Lo que sí podrías lograr es el comportamiento inverso, procesar algo en el servidor y escribir en un código javascript. Algo como lo siguiente

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var variable_from_server= '@Model.Variable_From_Server';
</script>
```

Espero que haya sido claro y sea útil.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Directamente no se puede... y aunque no es la mejor forma, se me ocurre que puedes generar un método con JS que llame a una función del controlador y asi entregarle el valor que tienes en JS.

Ejemplo:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ValorDesdeJS(string valueJS)
{
     //Tu código o asignación de variables a lo que necesites...
}
```

y desde JS podrias llamar a una funcion como esta:

```
function checkValidId(checkId)
{
    $.ajax({
         url: 'controllerName/ValorDesdeJS',
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json;',
         data: JSON.stringify({ valueJS: TuValorJS}),
         success: function (respuesta)
         {
              //código... 
         }
    });
}
```

después de eso, si quieres mostrarlo en la vista tendrías que pasarlo a través de un viewbag.